# Python: Convert tcpdump into text2pcap readable format

Tags: python, regex, networking, pcap, tcpdump

I've written a `Python` script to convert the textual output of `tcpdump -i eth0 -neXXs0` into a format understandable by `text2pcap`. This is my first `Python` program, and I'm looking for suggestions to enhance its efficiency, readability, or any potential discrepancies in the code.

The `tcpdump` output format I'm working with looks like this:

```
20:11:32.001190 00:16:76:7f:2b:b1 > 00:11:5c:78:ca:c0, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 72: 123.236.188.140.41756 > 94.59.34.210.45931: UDP, length 30
    
    0x0000:  0011 5c78 cac0 0016 767f 2bb1 0800 4500  ..\x....v.+...E.
    0x0010:  003a 0000 4000 4011 812d 7bec bc8c 5e3b  .:..@.@..-{...^;
    0x0020:  22d2 a31c b36b 0026 b9bd 2033 6890 ad33  "....k.&...3h..3
    0x0030:  e845 4b8d 2ba1 0685 0cb3 70dd 9b98 76d8  .EK.+.....p...v.
    0x0040:  8fc6 8293 bf33 325a                      .....32Z
```

**Output**

Format understandable by `text2pcap`:

```
20:11:32.001190 

    0000: 00 11 5c 78 ca c0 00 16 76 7f 2b b1 08 00 45 00   ..\x....v.+...E. 
    0010: 00 3a 00 00 40 00 40 11 81 2d 7b ec bc 8c 5e 3b   .:..@.@..-{...^; 
    0020: 22 d2 a3 1c b3 6b 00 26 b9 bd 20 33 68 90 ad 33   "....k.&...3h..3
    0030: e8 45 4b 8d 2b a1 06 85 0c b3 70 dd 9b 98 76 d8   .EK.+.....p...v. 
    0040: 8f c6 82 93 bf 33 32 5a   .....32Z
```

**Following is my Code:**

```
import re

# Identify time of the current packet.
time = re.compile('(..:..:..\.[\w]*) ')
# Get individual elements from the packet. ie. offset, hexdump, chars
all = re.compile('[ |\t]+0x([\w]+:) +(.+)  +(.*)')
# Regex for two spaces
twoSpaces = re.compile('  +')
# Regex for single space
singleSpace = re.compile(' ')
# Single byte pattern.
singleBytePattern = re.compile(r'([\w][\w])')

# Open files.
f = open('pcap.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('ashu.txt', 'w')

for line in f:
    result = time.match(line)
    if result:
        # If current line contains time format dump only time
        print(result.group())
        outfile.write(result.group() + '\n')
    else:
        print(line)
        # Split line containing hex dump and tokenize into list elements.
        result = all.split(line)
        if result:
            i = 0
            for values in result:
                if i == 2:
                    # Strip off additional spaces in hex dump
                    # Useful when hex dump does not end in 16 bytes boundary.
                    val = twoSpaces.sub('', values)

                    # Tokenize individual elements separated by single space.
                    byteResult = singleSpace.split(val)
                    for twoByte in byteResult:
                        # Identify individual byte
                        singleByte = singleBytePattern.split(twoByte)
                        byteOffset = 0
                        for oneByte in singleByte:
                            if byteOffset == 1 or byteOffset == 3:
                                # Write out individual byte with a space char appended
                                print(oneByte, end=' ')
                                outfile.write(oneByte + ' ')
                            byteOffset += 1
                elif i == 3:
                    # Write of char format of hex dump
                    print("  " + values, end='')
                    outfile.write('  ' + values + ' ')
                elif i == 4:
                    outfile.write(values)
                else:
                    print(values, end=' ')
                    outfile.write(values + ' ')
                i += 1
        else:
            print("could not split")
f.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: For starters, you should indent your comments to the same level as the code they refer to. It is very distracting to see the indentation broken up the way it currently is.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-w`  option of `tcpdump` to write to a pcap format file

```
tcpdump -w filename.pcap
```

Wireshark should be able to read it.

Comment: The requirement is that I just have the hexdump in a *.txt file format. This *.txt file needs to be converted into a *.pcap format so that I can replay it with 'tcpreplay' command.

Comment: Since no one has responded should I assume that my code is perfect.

Comment: There is no `perfect code` :-) only individual choices on how to code a for purpose. With Python, I am certain there will be a dozen variations possible -- some very short too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a powershell equivalent.  text2pcap.exe accepts it but I do get mostly "Inconsistent offset. Expecting 0, got 10. Ignoring rest of packet" warnings.  Wireshark opens but doesn't look right.  I'm going to check my tcpdump operands and text2pcap operands to see if I can get it to look better.

Providing code below in case it helps someone.

```
$text.split(10)|forEach{ if($_ -notmatch"0x"){$_} else { $num = [regex]::match($_,"(?<=0x)\d.*:").value ; $hex = [regex]::matches($_," \w.+").value.trim().replace(" ","") |%{$_ -split ("([a-z0-9]{2})")}; [string]$num,[string]$hex -join " "} }

2023-03-20 13:20:04.309607 IP 192.168.0.2.443 > 192.168.0.10.56321: Flags [.], ack 11801, win 498, length 0
0000:  45  00  00  28  3d  e9  40  00  ff  06  00  00  c0  a8  0c  57 E..(=.@........W
0010:  0a  fc  16  ba  01  bb  dc  01  38  29  25  31  51  97  cd  b6 ........8)% 1Q ...
0020:  50  10  01  f2  00  00  00  00 P.......
```